# Doubt from Arnold; Mathematical methods of classical mechanics (page 20)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator, approximations

I am trying to do a problem from Arnold; Mathematical methods of Classical mechanics.
But I didn't get the desired result mentioned by the author.

> Let $E_0$ be the value of the potential function at a minimum point $\xi$. Find the period $T_0 =
> \lim_{E\to E_0} T(E)$ of small oscillations in a neighbourhood of the point $\xi$.

Answer: $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{U''(\xi)}}$,
Where $U(\xi)$ is the potential energy.

Comment: Hint: The period is just $P=2 \pi/ \omega$, where $ \omega$ is the pulsation. For a potential of the form $U=U'' x^2/2$... (the mass is 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an important result with a large scope.

Let $U$ be the potential with a minimum for $x=\xi$. Taylor expansion near $\xi$ is:

$$U(x)\simeq U(\xi)+(x-\xi)U'(\xi)+\frac{1}{2}(x-\xi)^2U''(\xi)$$

Since $\xi$ is the location of a minimum, you have both:

$$U'(\xi)=0\\
U''(\xi)>0$$

Conservation of mechanical energy yields, with $k=U''(\xi)$:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{2}\,m\dot{x}^2+U(x)\right)=0
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
m\ddot{x}+k(x-\xi)=0
$$

You can read directly in this harmonic oscillator equation the angular frequency:

$$\omega^2=\frac{k}{m}$$

and the associated period:

$$T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{m}{U''(\xi)}}$$

$m$ is missing in the result you mention. Perhaps $U$ is redefined to contain $m$, or $U$ is a gravitational potential instead of a potential energy. But you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot, thanks for the simple explanation @Miyase